# fprintf: print literal hex string

Tags: c++, printf

Suppose I have a hex string that I have calculated from a set of bytes, in a particular format that suits me:

```
std::string s("#00ffe1");
```

And I less than sign it to std::cout

```
std::cout << s;

//prints:
#00ffe1
```

Although I like the way cout works, for my purposes it is easier to use `fprintf`, as this is outputting a formatted string that is just easier with `fprintf`.

I go to write the same string from `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(stdout,"foo=%s",s);

// outputs:
G* // (i.e., nonsense)
```

How do I output this string using `fprintf`?

Comment: what is wrong with using `cout << "foo=" << s;`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau nothing against it, just becomes a lot when formatting within brackets, braces, and many values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to convert the `std::string` to a null-terminated `const char*` using its `c_str()` member function:

```
fprintf(stdout,"foo=%s",s.c_str());
```

Note that this is still C++, even if you use `fprintf()`. C does not contain a data type `std::string`.

Comment: @bordeo Not really, since a variadic function (one with `...` as a parameter) can't really do type-checking at compile-time

Comment: Actually, several modern compilers DO now offer compile-time validation of printf-style function parameters, where passing a `std::string` to `%s` would be a mismatch that fails validation.

Comment: @GovindParmar in the past, I think I got some heads up--a segfault

Answer (score 5):

`std::string` is a class, not a "string" as the term applies in C (where `fprintf` comes from). the `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char []`. Use the `std::string` method `c_str()` to return the null-terminated-string, and pass *that* to `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(..., s.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

`fprintf` expects a C-style string, `char*`. `std::string` has a `c_str()` method that returns just that:

```
fprintf(stdout, "foo=%s", s.c_str());
```